# Will creating a new task generate a background thread or a thread pool thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, async-await

I'm trying to make a database call async for an ASP.NET application. If I understand things correctly, I do not want to utilize thread pool threads for async I/O calls so I can keep the thread pool processing requests. Will the code below chew up a thread from my thread pool or generate a background thread?

```
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> DbCall(string sql)
    {
        return // DB Operation;
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> DbCallAsync(string sql)
    {
        var task = new Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(() => this.DbCall(sql));
        task.Start();
        return task;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the `Task` constructor executes the code in another thread, in this case a thread pool thread.

You should be using a DB operation that is inherently asynchronous, not synchronous.  You should not be using the `Task` constructor at all to construct a `Task` that represents an asynchronous operation.  How you go about doing this will depend on what API you're using to perform your IO.

Comment: I'm using simple.data, which does not have async support. I'm trying to figure out how to call it async. The issue is that I need to run 5 sql statements in parallel. I don't want to be block 6 thread pool threads to accomplish this.

Comment: @DaleAlleshouse Then start using a querying mechanism that *does* have asynchronous support and that allows you to perform your query without blocking a thread.  If you don't, you have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks on the default scheduler run on the thread-pool. They do not, by default, start new threads. This answers your question.

That said, you misunderstand the purpose and inner workings of async IO. Async IO, while running, does not consume any thread at all. You are not using async IO however. You are moving IO to the thread-pool. This never helps in ASP.NET. It always reduced performance.

How could it possibly help to move blocking work to a different thread?! You are still blocking a thread. Just a different one. If your thread-pool is exhausted just increase the limits. No need to start threads manually.

Research *why* async is beneficial and when. Without this understanding you are not going to be successful using it.

Comment: I clarified a bit... This is the XY-Problem anyway.

Comment: Well, I guess I don't understand then. I was under the impression that it would release the current thread that was handling the I/O operation back to the thread pool until the I/O operation completes.

Comment: @DaleAlleshouse it does. But the IO operation now runs synchronously on a different thread. You win nothing doing that.